# Conditionally prevent Bootstrap 4 modal closing on "esc"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using session storage to show and hide a modal when loading the page for the first time. I don't know how to use cookies so I just use session storage.

In the modal, I change the header and the close button when you close it for the first time, then is accessible as a "help modal" instead of "getting started".

I want to prevent to close the modal with `esc` if the session storage is not set up and is in "getting started" mode, but when you close the modal and you reopen it as a "help modal" enable the `esc` event.

At the moment I make it work at 50%, first time you can't use `esc` but if you open it as a "help" you still can't use `esc`, although, if you reload the page `esc` it works,

Here is the `else` part of my code, effective when the session storage is not setup:

```
} else {
  // show the help modal
  $('#help').modal({
    keyboard: false
  });

  $('#help').modal('show');

  $('#help').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    keyboard: true
  })
}
```

The documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)
said that the `.on('hidden.bs.modal'` event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user.

Which event I have to use to make it works as I want?

Comment: Mate, the alpha version is vastly outdated compared to the current beta 3 version...

Comment: sorry, I'm using the beta 3 version not the alpha, just the documentation is alpha

Comment: So, why would you want to quote the wrong documentation then?

Comment: This is the link you need: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: sorry, i've updated the correct link, the documentation is the same, same events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, you cannot simply re-configure an already initialized modal by supplying new `options` object to it. Meaning that if you do the following:

```
$('#help').modal({
    keyboard: false
});

$('#help').modal({
    keyboard: true
});
```

…than the latter statement won't have any effect.
So, in order to overcome this, I would suggest to destroy the first modal –the one with `keyboard: false`– and create a new modal that listens to keyboard events too.

Check the working snippet below.
Note: the first modal is created at pageload from code using `keyboard: false`, while consecutive modals launched by the button are set with the defaults, so with `keyboard: true`.

```js
// } else {
    // show the help modal
    $('#help').modal({
        keyboard: false
    });

    // Note the `one` binding
    $('#help').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $('#help').modal('dispose');
    });
// }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#help">
    Open Help
</button>


<div id="help" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">HELP</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is the Help modal</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```